# ArmSim assembly comparing bits from an input string

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to write a program that reads the entire string from an input file. Then, it replaces letters with the symbol "*" and numbers with the symbol "#". Anything else remains the same. I got my program to read the string and check the first bit to see if it is a number or a letter. How do I move to the next bit and keep comparing until the end of the string?
this my code so far:

```
   .equ SWI_Open,0x66     @ open a file
.equ SWI_Close,0x68    @ close a file
.equ SWI_PrStr,0x69    @ Write a null-ending string 
.equ SWI_RdStr,0x6a    @ read a string from file
.equ SWI_PrInt,0x6b    @ Write an Integer
.equ Stdout, 1         @ Set output target to be Stdout
.equ SWI_Exit,0x11     @ Stop execution
.global _start
_start:
@ ========= Open file for reading =============================
ldr r0,=myFile        
mov r1,#0       
swi SWI_Open          @ open file
bcs InFileError       @ if cannot open file branch to InFileError 
ldr r1,=InputFileHandle
str r0,[r1]
@ ========== Read String ======================================= 
ldr r0,=InputFileHandle
ldr r0,[r0]
ldr r1,=array
mov r2,#1024
swi SWI_RdStr
bcs emptyFile        @ branch if file is empty
mov r3,#0
mov r5,r0            @ number of characters
mov r6,r1            @ address of string
mov r7,#0x30
mov r8,#0x39
mov r9,#0x41
mov r10,#0x5A
mov r11,#0x61
mov r12,#0x7A
@ ===============================
Loop:
ldrb r4,[r6]
cmp r4,r7
BLT sim
cmp r4,r8
BLE Num
cmp r4,r9
BLT sim
cmp r4,r10
BLE Letter
InFileError:
mov R0, #Stdout
ldr R1, =FileOpenInpErrMsg
swi SWI_PrStr 
bal Exit

emptyFile:
mov R0, #Stdout
ldr R1, =FileEmpty
swi SWI_PrStr 
bal Exit 

Letter:
mov r4,#'*
strb r4,
add r4,r4,#1
bal Loop

Num:


sim:
add r5,r5,#1

InputFileHandle: .word 0
array: .skip 1024
FileEmpty: .asciz "File is Empty"
myFile: .asciz "input.txt"
FileOpenInpErrMsg: .asciz "Error opening file \n"
EndOfFileMsg: .asciz "End of file reached\n"
NL: .asciz "\n " @ new line
.end
```

Comment: What have you tried, and in what does it do differently from what you want?  (Showing some code might be nice.)

Comment: my code keeps comparing the first bit and it does not go to the next one

Comment: Without seeing any code, its kind of hard to help much.

Comment: i just added my code

Answer (score 0):

- Since `r6` contains the address of your string, that's the memory location that needs to get changed if it is a letter or number
- That also means that it needs to be bumped up by 1 to get to the next character in the string
- Be careful using `bal`; if that stands for *branch and link*, then you should only be using it to jump to a subroutine (the *link* being how you get back from it)

Comment: **`bal` in ARM is Branch ALways, the same as `b`**.  (Remember ARM-mode (not Thumb) instructions always have a 4-bit predicate.  ALways is the default if you omit a condition suffix in the asm source).  Branch and Link is `bl`.

Answer (score 0):

use:
ldrb r4,[r6],#1
instead of
ldrb r4,[r6]